# GSON Integer to Boolean for Specific Fields

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm dealing with an API that sends back integers (1=true, other=false) to represent booleans.

I've seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399079/convert-ints-to-booleans), but I need to be able to specify which field this should apply to, since some times an integer is actually an integer.

**EDIT:** The incoming JSON could possibly look like this (could also be String instead of int, etc...):

```
{ 
    "regular_int": 1234, 
    "int_that_should_be_a_boolean": 1
}
```

I need a way to specify that `int_that_should_be_a_boolean` should be parsed as a boolean and `regular_int` should be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We will provide Gson with a little hook, a custom deserializer for booleans, i.e. a class that implements the `JsonDeserializer<Boolean>` interface:

**CustomBooleanTypeAdapter**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.*;
class BooleanTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                           JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    if (((JsonPrimitive) json).isBoolean()) {
        return json.getAsBoolean();
    }
    if (((JsonPrimitive) json).isString()) {
        String jsonValue = json.getAsString();
        if (jsonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            return true;
        } else if (jsonValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    int code = json.getAsInt();
    return code == 0 ? false :
            code == 1 ? true : null;
  }
}
```

To use it we’ll need to change a little the way we get the `Gson` mapper instance, using a factory object, the GsonBuilder, a common pattern way to use `GSON` is here.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new BooleanTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

For primitive Type use below one

```
 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, new BooleanTypeAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Enjoy the `JSON` parsing!

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, any time I try to deserialize with this `BooleanTypeAdapter` set, any `boolean` will be treated this way?

Comment: @Maheshwar Ligade So what about the question **specific fields** part?
This solution doesn't work for responses contain normal integer value like `quantity : 0` this key can't represented as `Boolean`

Comment: How does it work if I have a normal boolean field in my json together with ones represented by integer values?

Comment: The trick here is that the parameter type in the Java class determines what adapter to use. So if `quantity` is an `int`, it will use the standard integer adapter. If `quantity` is a `boolean`, it will use the custom boolean adapter (that will pull the value from 0 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to normalize or massage the value on the incoming JsonReader from an int to something else, like a boolean.

If so, you probably want to create an adapter class that extends TypeAdapter<YourFieldNameType> and overrides read(). You get the value from nextInt() and then return the appropriate boolean based on its value. You may have to check for null values, depending on the config of the parser.

If you need to, you can override write() in the same adapter class, to coerce booleans in your client code into integers for the JsonWriter.

[EDIT]

For reference, here is an example of my TypeAdapter, which coerces a "Commands" enum class to/from an integer.

```
package com.company.product.json;

import static com.company.product.Commands.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import com.company.product.Commands;
import com.company.product.client.ClientSocket;

/**
 * Adapter for Command handling.
 * 
 * We write out the CommandName as an Integer, and read it in as a Commands constant.
 * 
 * This satisfies the requirement that the CommandName by represented by JSON as an int, but allows
 * us to deserialize it to a Commands object on read.
 * 
 * @author jdv
 * @see com.company.product.Command#commandName CommandName
 */
public class CommandsAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Commands> {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientSocket.class.getPackage().getName());

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc) Deserialize the JSON "CommandName" integer into the corresponding Commands
   * constant object.
   * 
   * @see com.google.gson.TypeAdapter#read(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader)
   */
  @Override
  public Commands read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

    final int command;
    try {
      command = in.nextInt();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      logger.severe("Unable to read incoming JSON stream: " + e.getMessage());
      throw new IOException(e);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      logger
          .severe("Unable to read and convert CommandName Integer from the incoming JSON stream: "
              + e.getMessage());
      throw new IOException(e);
    }

    // Let's not risk using a bad array index. Not every command is expected
    // by the WebSocket handlers, but we should do our best to construct
    // a valid Commands object.
    if (command < NO_OP.getValue() || command > LAST_COMMAND.getValue()) {
      throw new IOException(new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Unexpected value encountered for Commands constant: " + command));
    } else {
      return Commands.values()[command];
    }
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc) Serialize Commands object constants as their Integer values.
   * 
   * @see com.google.gson.TypeAdapter#write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter, java.lang.Object)
   */
  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, Commands value) throws IOException {
    out.value(value.getValue());
  }

}
```

This essentially adapts incoming and outgoing ops on the "CommandName" serialized param that is locally represented as a "Commands" enum and as an integer remotely. Anything to do with this Commands enum is filtered through this adapter class that overrides read() and write(). Eventually this drives a WebSocket peer, but none of that really matters for the purpose of this discussion. HTH.

Comment: Let's say that there are some integer values that I want to treat as boolean, and some that I want to treat as integers, as I stated in the last sentence of the question.

Comment: If they are from the same serialized field on the JsonReader, you are going to have to put additional logic in read() to make your decision and return the right thing. But, in a nutshell, if you need to munge incoming or outgoing types to some other type, you need to create a TypeAdapter class for those types.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain the problem a little more clearly.

Comment: Gson is very type-oriented. The name is for the serialized field, AFAIK, so can't help you on deserialization. You might have to create a new destination container type that will coerce "1" into a boolean, or possibly create your own parser so you have access to the field names. There is also FieldAttributes which might be a way for you to hook into the fieldname on a custom deserializer.